# How to link one file from a git repo to another repo

Tags: git

I have a git repo structure like this:

`mylib.git` is where I curate a lot of utility functions. `program.git` is where I am writing new code. I need the code in `program` to access one of my utility functions, `mylib/adder.py`. Now I could just put a copy of `adder.py` in `program/` but if I make changes to `mylib/adder.py` then they won't propagate to `program/`. Is there a way in git to link `mylib/adder.py` to the `program/` directory, so that I can still benefit from version control on `program/adder.py`?

I know the user could just clone both my `mylib` and `program` repos, but I am hoping to make a `program.git` repo that is self-standing while still taking advantage of version control for the `adder` code.

Comment: Have a look at git submodules or git subtrees.

Comment: Use git submodules?

Comment: Consider looking into a seperate dependency manager? Or maybe use a symlink?

Comment: Package management matters.  Make a package from `mylib.git`.  Install it.  Use it with the code in `program.git`.  Don't try to emulate a library by copy-n-paste.  It leads down a rabbit hole of problems. IOW, use your library as a libray.

Comment: Thanks William! I'm sitting here now thinking "Derp. Shoulda thought of that."